# Yii2: Translate Application Name

Tags: yii2, translation

How to properly translate the name of the application in Yii2?

We can easily set the [application name](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-application#$name-detail) in `main-local.php` (or `config/main.php`) like so:

```
$config = [
    'name'  => 'My Application Name',
    // ...
];
```

But how would we translate it?

Using something like `\Yii::t('app.name', 'My Application Name')` does not work because the configuration file is parsed before the application language is even determined or set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to do translation on actual usage of application name:

```
<?= \Yii::t('app.name', Yii::$app->name) ?>
```

For messages extraction you may use fake translation in comment. Not sure about Poedit, but built-in Yii extractor support this some time ago:

```
$config = [
    // \Yii::t('app.name', 'My Application Name')
    'name'  => 'My Application Name',
    // ...
];
```

In worst case you may create separate file for such fake translations only for messages extraction, and don't include it on actual execution.

Comment: This works, the only problem is, it makes extracting the string very difficult (Poedit for example will miss it).